# SSH troubleshooting from outside my apartment to inside

Tags: networking, routing, traceroute

I'm trying to be able to ssh from outside (for example at work) to a computer in my home network.

This was working at my last apartment. I was on xfinity cable. I setup dynamic dns on my router (an EdgeRouterX). I also set up port forwarding to forward port 22 from the outside to the server on my home network. This all worked great!

Recently I moved to a new apartment. The new apartment has free internet from [Hotwire Communications](https://hotwirecommunications.com/). The equipment hasn't changed. It's all setup the same. While on my home network I can `ssh 192.168.1.50` (in ip address of the machine running sshd on my local network). But, I can not ssh to the public IP address. For example if I go to https://whatismyipaddress.com/, it gives me an address (example: 165.69.241.170 [not real]))

Checking my home domain, the one registered to be updated via dynamic dns, it matches (example is not the real domain)

```
❯ dig myhome.mypersonaldomain.net 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> umyhome.mypersonaldomain.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10210
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myhome.mypersonaldomain.net.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myhome.mypersonaldomain.net.    180 IN  A   165.69.241.170

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 01 01:0
```

So I can see the dynamic dns updater has correctly updated the domain's IP address

But, neither `ssh myhome.mypersonaldomain.net` nor `ssh 165.69.241.170` respond at all.

I called them and they claimed nothing is blocked but on the other hand I don't trust customer service people at companies like that. Usually they are just reading answers fron a knowledge base.

I don't know if traceroute would help but doing a `traceroute google.com` never shows that IP address.

Doing a [traceroute online](https://traceroute-online.com/) back to that ip address I don't see it get to 165.69.241.170.  It ends at ???

```
1   172.17.0.1              0.0%    0.12ms
2   10.206.5.139                0.0%    0.32ms
3   10.206.35.7             0.0%    0.47ms
4   10.206.32.2             0.0%    1.16ms
5   lo0-0.gw2.cjj1.us.linode.com
173.255.239.102 AKAMAI-LINODE-AP Akamai Connected Cloud, SG 173.255.239.0/24        0.0%    0.63ms
6   ???                 
7   ???                 
8   ???                 
9   100ge0-56.core3.ash1.he.net
184.105.81.150  HURRICANE, US   184.104.0.0/15      50.0%   45.37ms
10  ???                 
11  hotwire.port-channel5.switch5.lax2.he.net
216.218.227.202 HURRICANE, US   216.218.128.0/17        0.0%    67.38ms
12  10.120.0.64             0.0%    68.70ms
13  ???
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue and find out the cause?

Comment: Does the IP address as reported by "whatismyipaddress" match the IP address acquired by your router?

Comment: You will need to forward the port to your device, if you cannot forward the port, it means your behind a CGNAT.

Comment: The port already is forwarded to my device as mentioned above ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5X8B.png)). I will call them and ask about CGNAT. Is there any way I can detect CGNAT so that I have something to point to other than saying "It doesn't work"?